# VBA autofilter creating a 1004 error when copy between workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

Creating a macro that filters a table of data and copies that data to another workbook.

Consistently getting error 1004 highlighting the autofilter as the issue. The grp variable criteria applies to column B.

The source data is in 'thisworkbook' and the destination of the data is the activeworkbook.

Any ideas would be appreciated. I feel like there is something simple I'm missing

```
    dim grp as string
    dim wb as workbook
    set workbook = activeworkbook      
    grp = wb.Worksheets(1).Name
    Debug.Print grp
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CSAT").Range("A11:Y5000")
        .AutoFilter field:=2, _
        criteria:=grp
    End With
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CSAT").Range("A1:Y" & getLRow(Sheets("CSAT"), 1)).Copy
    With wb.Sheets("Customer Satisfaction").Range("A11")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End With
```

Comment: `Dim wb as activeworkbook` makes no sense. It should be `Dim wb as Workbook` and later on `Set wb = ActiveWorkBook`

Comment: Try setting criteria as criteria1 instead `criteria1:=grp`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns apologies, this dim is definied elsewhere in the code and wanted to make sure that it was obvious what wb was so typed it in manually and too quickly. It is defined correctly in the actual code.

Comment: @Plutian this is brilliant! Thanks!. If only the vba editor could alert me when I make stupid mistakes like this

Comment: If only, it would make half this website redundant! I'll post it as an answer as well so the question can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Autofilter can take 2 criteria to filter by default, sorted by priority. Therefore you should specify what the first and second criteria is so it can determine which to prioritise: `criteria1:= filterthisfirst` `criteria2:= filterthisafter` accounting for duplicates in criteria1.

However if you don't specify criteria 1 or 2 specifically, it doesn't recognise it as a criteria since doesn't match of the options, resulting in an error. Same if you feed it criteria 2 but not 1.